# Make scrollbar custom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a way to make scrollbar below and its actually work, but I don't know how to hide the original scrollbar and only show the scrollbar in the picture, I'm still so new please help me.

[image]

**HTML:-**

```
    <div class="parent">
            <div class="scrollbar"></div>
            <div class="scrollable">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                 consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. 
                 Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.</p> 
           </div>
   </div>
```

**css:-**

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
       margin:50px;
      overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background:#ddd;
}
.scrollable{
      overflow-y:scroll;
    position:absolute;
      padding:0 17px 0 0;
    width: 180px;
      height:100%;
}
.scrollbar{

    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#444;
    width:7px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**Javascript:-**

```
  var $scrollable = $('.scrollable');
  var $scrollbar  = $('.scrollbar');
  $scrollable.outerHeight(true);
  var H   = $scrollable.outerHeight(true);
  var sH  = $scrollable[0].scrollHeight;
  var  sbH = H*H/sH;



$('.scrollbar').height(sbH);

$scrollable.on("scroll", function(){

    $scrollbar.css({top: $scrollable.scrollTop()/H*sbH });
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome the original scrollbar is hidden!

Comment: Add `width: 100%;` to the `.scrollable` css

Comment: Hi I did but its still there.

Comment: This is the same example and it works on web, but doesn't work when I copy it to my project, that is so weird http://jsbin.com/nikuwi/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yes, I created a jsfiddle to test it, and it was working... Are you sure your local version is the newest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118696/discussion-between-simon-kirsten-and-pexichdu).

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly. what is the problem. Make sure you have link following two files and your computer is connected with the internet connection

//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"

//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"

```js
var $scrollable = $('.scrollable'),
    $scrollbar  = $('.scrollbar'),
    H   = $scrollable.outerHeight(true),
    sH  = $scrollable[0].scrollHeight,
    sbH = H*H/sH;

 $('.scrollbar').height( sbH ).draggable({
    axis : 'y',
  containment : 'parent', 
   drag: function(e, ui) {
   $scrollable.scrollTop( sH/H*ui.position.top  );
    }
}); 
 
$scrollable.on("scroll", function(){
 $scrollbar.css({top: $scrollable.scrollTop()/H*sbH });
});
```

```css
.parent{
    position:relative;
    margin:50px;
   overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background:#ddd;
}
.scrollable{
   overflow-y:scroll;
    position:absolute;
   padding:0 17px 0 0;
    width: 180px;
   height:100%;
}
.scrollbar{
    cursor:n-resize;
    position:absolute;
   overflow:auto;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#444;
    width:17px;
    border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


 
<div class="parent">
    <div class="scrollbar"></div>
    <div class="scrollable">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.

    </div>
</div>
```